# Easiest way to get two arrays have the same length?

Tags: c, arrays, declare

There are two arrays in my projects. One is of static const type which contain more or less entries on different projects, like

```
static const array_A[] = { ... };
```

I do not like the style of `array_A[N] = { ... }` since I do not want to count the length of array manually.

There is another array B whose length is required to be the same as A.

Some compiler (such as armcc) support the following trick

```
const int N = sizeof(array_A) / sizeof(array_A[0])
static const array_B[N];
```

But this trick fails with gcc compiler. So is there any other easy way ?

Comment: what do you mean by it fails? it clearly [works for me.](http://ideone.com/CTSfDl)

Comment: You are missing a type name in both your array declarations.

Comment: @ZacWrangler, he tagged C, not c++. Code in C compiles with clang, not gcc.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting that:

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
const int N = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
const int b[N];
```

Compiles with clang, does not compile with gcc 4.2.1:

```
error: variably modified ‘b’ at file scope
```

OP asked for C, not C++, so a fix for gcc would be

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
const int b[sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])];
```

Comment: It does work. So this should be a gcc bug?

Comment: I would not call it a gcc bug. The C language has evolved over the years, and compilers struggle to keep up and they add extensions of their own. This feature may or may not be in any C specification, I don't know. You could ask SO if this feature is found in any official C spec if you were interested.